# Widths of layered rectangles do not behave as expected

Tags: android

[image: background]

I am trying to achieve the above background with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#dddddd" />
            <size android:width="0dp" android:height="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#aaaaaa" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#6bb726" />
            <size android:width="3dp" android:height="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

However, setting rectangle widths does not seem to be working and the green rectangle is taking as much space as the grey rectangle.

[image: unexpected background]

Can anyone suggest improvements to my xml-defined shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:right="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#6bb726" />
            <size android:width="3dp" android:height="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#dddddd" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#aaaaaa" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



</layer-list>
```

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:right="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#6bb726" />
            <size android:width="3dp" android:height="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item  android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#aaaaaa" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp" android:top="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#dddddd" />


            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



</layer-list>
```

Comment: It works but I want the stroke on the left side to disappear and the green rectangle to take its place.

Comment: hope I could something like this myself one day